# How to put the values of column A to row A and keep the values of the dataset unchanged?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, r

I've got a large dataset with 10 variables (columns) and 10k rows.

One of the columns is Year, going from 2000 to 2014. I want the values of the Year to be joined with the names of the variables.

Here's what I want to do in pictures (it's a bit complicated to explain it).

How it is now:

[image]

How I want it to be:

[image]

I could use Excel or R for doing this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pivot table:

- Select a cell in your range
- Insert pivot table
- Following settings:

[image]

- Optional; Change column titles if need be and turn of totals.
- Optional; Change field settings of `Sector` > check the Repeat item labels box and make sure Show item labels in tabular form is selected.
- Relevant output:

[image]

- If you don't want to have a pivot table, you can still copy/paste the relevant cells into your own matrix. Copy, in my example `H3:O7` and paste them whereever on another sheet for example `A1` on sheet2:

[image]

- Headers of column C:H can be obtained through formula, type the following in `C1`:

  ```
  =IF(ISEMPTY(Sheet1!J2),Sheet1!I2&"_"&Sheet1!J3,Sheet1!J2&"_"&Sheet1!J3)
  ```
- Obviously change ranges according to your pivot table range, and drag right...

[image]

Comment: ,, you have not shown that how you got the data in final format !!

Comment: @RajeshS, what do you mean? I mentioned copy/paste the data.

Comment: ,, these screen shots are different than previous,, since you have edited minutes before,,, and if one Copy & Paste PT results then how Heading suppose to re-written, are different than PT!!

Comment: @RajeshS, I have only edited one screenshot (the second one) to show how to hide totals and edited columns would look like. The follow-up (about copy-paste) is still the same. I don't know what you on about. I though copy-paste is very basic. Yes, the headers need to be entered manually once.

Comment: I've raised point related to the HEADERS,, which can't be Copy & Paste as final results,, also OP's output has Sector value,, check the attached screen shots with OP !!

Comment: @RajeshS, it's edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96802/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-jvdv).

Comment: I forgot to add some ```NA``` values in my examples. My data set contains plenty of them. So, in the columns, there actually are both numerical and textual values such as ```NA```.

The problem arises when I ask my pivot table to show values as sums. It returns me ```0``` instead of ```NA```, which is not as I want because this mixes up the old data set's ```0s``` with ```NAs```.

Is there a way to make the pivot table show both numerical and textual values as they were in the old data set?

Comment: @KenLee, try removing all NA, values in your old data set. Should be a simple task, replace all "NA" with "". Then click any cell in the pivottable, and under Pivot table options > Show empty cells as > Type "NA"

Comment: I tried this but I fail to have any blanks in my pivot table. I get `0s`.

By default, my pivot table shows values as counts instead of sums. So in the beginning, I start with `1s` everywhere. Then I change it to show sums. After that, it has too many `0s` and no blanks/`NAs`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @KenLee, I have no other suggestion then what I previoulsy mentioned. It worked for  me. Steps > Replace all `NA` in your old data set with nothing, so they are empty. > Change the valuetype to `SUM` > Show empty cells as "NA"

Comment: @KenLee, did you actually refresh your pivot table after you changed the settings?